# Sumar cantidades en stock

Tags: php

Necesito esta ocasión sumar cantidades en stock, ejemplo, cuando se hace el registro del algún `item` se agrega una cantidad de entrada por ejemplo `2`, pero mas adelante se quiere actualizar ese mismo `item` agregándole `2 más`, en total deben ser `4`.

He intentado de diferentes maneras de hacerlo pero no he tenido éxito, en mi código al inicio intento guardar el valor actual antes de que este sea actualizado, posteriormente se hace un `update` con la nueva cantidad, después obtengo el nuevo valor, y hago la suma de las dos cantidades, para finalizar hago de nuevo un `update` enviando la nueva cantidad en el campo `quantityTicket`

Haciendo las respectivas pruebas, no suma la cantidad solamente la cambia al valor agregado, es decir si tengo 4 y agrego 2, la nueva cantidad es 2. lo que es completamente erróneo.

¿Alguien me podría apoyar con esto?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        if(isset($_POST['quantityTicket'])&& isset($_POST['price_Ticket'])  && isset($_POST['comentTicket']) && isset($_POST['unit_Ticket']) && isset($_POST['id_ticket']))
          {
            $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Tijuana');
            $hoy = date("Y-m-d");

            $selectQty = "SELECT quantityTicket from inventory_ticket where id_ticket = ?";//selecciono el valor actual y lo guardo
            $getQty = $connection->executeNonQuery($selectQty,array($_POST['quantityTicket']));//se guarda el valor actual


              $query = "UPDATE inventory_ticket
                        SET quantityTicket = ?,price_Ticket=?,registerTicket=?,comentTicket=?,unit_Ticket=? WHERE id_ticket = ?";
                        //se actualiza quantityTickey con una cantidad nueva

              $result = $connection->executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['quantityTicket'], $_POST['price_Ticket'], $hoy, $_POST['comentTicket'], $_POST['unit_Ticket'] , $_POST['id_ticket']));
              //postea la nueva cantidad

              $newQty = "SELECT quantityTicket from inventory_ticket where id_ticket = ?"; // obtengo la nueva cantidad
              $getNewQty = $connection->executeNonQuery($newQty,array($_POST['quantityTicket']));//la guardo

              $sumQty =intval($getQty[0][0] + intval($getNewQty[0][0])); //suma del valor actual a la cantidad nueva


              $allQty = 'UPDATE inventory_ticket set quantityTicket = quantityTicket + ?  where id_ticket = ?'; //actualizo el campo
              $resultQty = $connection->executeNonQuery($allQty,array($sumQty,$_POST['id_ticket'])); //posteo l anueva cantidad
              if ($result == 0)
              {
                echo json_encode(array(
                  'status' => '0',
                  'errorMessage' => 'entrada actualizado'
                ));
              }
```

Comment: En el `UPDATE` cuando hagas el `SET` debes incrementar la cantidad del campo más lo que envías como parámetro `quantityTicket = quantityTicket + ?` el error lo tienes en que hacer un primer `UPDATE` y ese es el que hace que se te suceda lo que comentas. Ese primer `UPDATE` a mi parecer es totalmente innecesario para lo que quieres lograr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso del Update, debería ser:

```
$query = "UPDATE inventory_ticket
                        SET quantityTicket = quantityTicket + ?,price_Ticket=?,registerTicket=?,comentTicket=?,unit_Ticket=? WHERE id_ticket = ?";
                        //se actualiza quantityTickey con una cantidad nueva
```

o decrementa:

```
$query = "UPDATE inventory_ticket
                        SET quantityTicket = quantityTicket - ?,price_Ticket=?,registerTicket=?,comentTicket=?,unit_Ticket=? WHERE id_ticket = ?";
                        //se actualiza quantityTickey con una cantidad nueva
```

No se si me comprendes.

La otra opción pero no recomendada es que al momento de guardar, obtengas el valor actual con un select y luego incrementas o decrementas al valor del select y le haces el update.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad,funciona perfectamente, y tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme.!